# What can I use to autograph a 3DS XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I'm looking to get my 3DS signed at PAX Prime, and I'm wondering what the best writing instrument would be for signing it.  Would a regular Sharpie work?

Also, what would be the best way to protect those autographs on the surface?

Comment: You'll probably want to figure out what material the 3DS is made out of, and how best to preserve a signature on that material. I'm not having much luck finding the material.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Mike!  While this question is tangentially related to gaming, it is not truly a gaming question - you could replace the 3DS with any object you want signed and the question remains the same.  As such, it is off-topic here.

Comment: "it is not truly a gaming question - you could replace the 3DS with any object you want signed and the question remains the same" - No you couldn't. The physical materials of an object determine what kinds of inks or markings can be signed on it and what kinds of coatings can protect it. That's like saying any question about repairs is only tangentially-related because you can ask "how can I repair <anything>?"

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Gamers are no more likely to be experts about how to preserve signatures than anyone else in the general population. That the signature is on a 3DS is immaterial to the required expertise. It doesn't require special gamer knowledge to figure out what it's made of and how to preserve a signature. It requires a screwdriver + reading moulding markings or practical materials-science expertise to just recognise it by look & feel, plus archival expertise. None of those are "gamer" things.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie but aren't gamers more likely to have done the research already, for gaming devices?

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Gamers are also more *likely* to know about the details of the Columbine shooting due to the excessive media assumptions about the connection to DOOM and Quake, but that doesn't make asking about non-game details about it on-topic. If it's not about games, it's off-topic by the FAQ. Making "gamers might be more likely to know" as the criteria for being on-topic opens the site to a huge variety of non-game questions, and that's just not going to happen.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Of course that's not a sufficient requirement by itself. It's also a question about a piece of hardware specifically for playing games. I can substitute "word processor" into most of the tech support questions on this site - that doesn't make them off-topic. It means I substituted in something off-topic. "That the signature is on a 3DS is immaterial to the required expertise." No really, it's not. The 3DS is a specific thing made of specific things. Gamers own it. Gamers have it signed. It plays games. It's a question about game hardware for gamers.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig "What is the best implement for autographing a hard plastic casing and then how can I preserve it against heavy wear?" That entirely preserves the question's content, would garner the same answers, and yet it has no gaming content. Not on-topic. Of course you're welcome to vote to reopen, or open a discussion on meta.

Comment: My apologies if this was considered offtopic; I thought it would fit here since it was about a gaming device (and depending on the materials, it being a 3DS may have made a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the 3DS like an autographed guitar: [Autographed Guitar Link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4866104_preserve-autographed-guitar.html)

Acrylic Method

1. If you haven't yet had the <del>guitar</del> 3DS autographed, make sure to have the autograph signed with an acrylic pen. Acrylic ink won't fade or bleed when sprayed with the protective clear coat.
2. Spray a fine mist of acrylic clear coat over the autographed area. One coat of the protective spray will work fine.
3. Allow the clear coat to dry before playing or moving the <del>guitar</del> 3DS.